# How to split a string with links into an array or object in PHP and throw away all content that doesn't belong to the url?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a list of links in my db column and when I grab it from the db it looks like this (obviously, it's much longer in reality):

```
http://example.com/asdfasdf/erwr
http://asdfasdfas.com/asdfasd/fasdf/asdfas.mp3
http://asdfa.com/adsf/asdf/asdf/asdf.html
```

or it can looks like this:

```
http://example.com/asdfasdf/erwrhttp://asdfasdfas.com/asdfasd/fasdf/asdfas.mp3
```

or it can looks like this:

```
http://example.com/asdfasdf/erwr, http://asdfasdfas.com/asdfasd/fasdf/asdfas.mp3
```

so I think that the indication of a new link is the beginning `http://` which will probably be not in the url itself except in the begining of that url.

So, the problem is how to explode this list in PHP and create an array or object with links and throw away all the other html like `<br>` or commas and spaces etc.

Any idea how to do that in PHP?

Comment: Why not write your urls as urls into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode string into array and can get your required string. 
For example

```
$url = http://example.com/asdfasdf/erwr
$string = explode('//',$url);
echo $string[1];

//output example.com/asdfasdf/erwr
```

Comment: hmm, what about this situation: 'http://example.com/asdfasdf//erwr'. I have some links like this.

Answer (score 0):

I´d go two-stepped. First use explode() with :// or alike to get strings starting with your url, and in a second step apply a regex to cut off each string at the first non-url-char (space etc.)